# How to compare two XML files and add missing elements using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Occasionally, one or more XML Elements are missing from XML File. Right now, one work around i am thinking is to compare XML file with a master XML File (having all the elements) and if any element is missing then add that element in XML File from master file.

How i gonna achieve this or any other better idea?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860128

Comment: i have nt get answer/solution yet. So just try to modify it to make it easy to understand.

Comment: Since it's not an *exact* duplicate, I'll vote to close your previous question.

Comment: Sonny. Those XML Files are generated by Third Party Tool. I really can't do anything to that. And thats what this little project is for to rectify the mistakes of Third Party Tool. Do you have any suggestion, how i gonna compare and add missing elements.

Answer (score 1):

One of the coolest libraries I've found while just looking around the Microsoft site is the XmlDiffPatch library. You can find more information at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx but it essentially allows you to compare two documents, find all the differences and then apply those differences. Very useful for compressing xml files to send across a network

Comment: Ya. its a cool stuff...but not gonna help in my case. I need to compare only elements (ignore Inner Text value), and if element is missing add a blank element.

Comment: Aaah... Sorry, I didn't catch that from your question... Well, more people should know about the DiffPatch library regardless...

Comment: Actually this solves your problem perfectly - just make sure the master XML contains blank elements.

Comment: Good point, I suppose it would work with a little bit of xml manipulation

Answer (score 0):

From [link text](http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?t=168067)

```
using System.Xml;

public class Form1
{

XmlDocument Doc1;
XmlDocument Doc2;

string Doc1Path = "C:\\XmlDoc1.xml";

private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    Doc1 = new XmlDocument();
    Doc2 = new XmlDocument();

    Doc1.Load(Doc1Path);
    Doc2.Load("C:\\XmlDoc2.xml");

    Compare();

    Doc1.Save(Doc1Path);

}

public void Compare()
{

    foreach (XmlNode ChNode in Doc2.ChildNodes) {
        CompareLower(ChNode);
    }

}

public void CompareLower(XmlNode NodeName)
{

    foreach (XmlNode ChlNode in NodeName.ChildNodes) {

        if (ChlNode.Name == "#text") {
            continue;
        }

        string Path = CreatePath(ChlNode);

        if (Doc1.SelectNodes(Path).Count == 0) {
            XmlNode TempNode = Doc1.ImportNode(ChlNode, true);
            Doc1.SelectSingleNode(Path.Substring(0, Path.LastIndexOf("/"))).AppendChild(TempNode);
            Doc1.Save(Doc1Path);
        }
        else {
            CompareLower(ChlNode);
            Doc1.Save(Doc1Path);
        }

    }

}

public string CreatePath(XmlNode Node)
{

    string Path = "/" + Node.Name;

    while (!(Node.ParentNode.Name == "#document")) {
        Path = "/" + Node.ParentNode.Name + Path;
        Node = Node.ParentNode;
    }
    Path = "/" + Path;
    return Path;

}
```

}

Comment: The only problem with this is it's an exponential time algorithm. You need something that does look at each element in doc1 for each element in doc2.

Answer (score 0):

In my example, the top level node is `<content>` so you'd just need to replace that for whatever your top level node is in your XML file.

```
public static void MergeMissingContentFileNodes(string sourceFile, string destFile)
{
    string topLevelNode = "content";

    XmlDocument srcXml = new XmlDocument();
    srcXml.Load(sourceFile);

    XmlDocument destXml = new XmlDocument();
    destXml.Load(destFile);

    XmlNode srcContentNode = srcXml.SelectSingleNode(topLevelNode);
    destXml = LoopThroughAndCreateMissingNodes(destXml, srcContentNode, topLevelNode);
    destXml.Save(destFile);

}

public static XmlDocument LoopThroughAndCreateMissingNodes(XmlDocument destXml, XmlNode parentNode, string parentPath)
{
    foreach (XmlNode node in parentNode.ChildNodes) 
    {
        //check if node exists and update destXML
        if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) 
        {
            string currentPath = string.Format("{0}/{1}", parentPath, node.Name);
            if (destXml.SelectSingleNode(currentPath) == null) 
            {
                dynamic destParentNode = destXml.SelectSingleNode(parentPath);
                destParentNode.AppendChild(destParentNode.OwnerDocument.ImportNode(node, true));
            }

            LoopThroughAndCreateMissingNodes(destXml, node, currentPath);

        }
    }

    return destXml;
}
```